# "system_server" - BluetoothPhoneService Causes High CPU Usage

Tags: processes, services

I am using Android 5.1 on Nexus 4 and noticed battery drain faster than usual a few months ago. Thinking I need to update Android to newer version I decided to check CPU usage first and found that process "system_server" - BluetoothPhoneService causes high CPU usage:

[image]

Researched on other forums and other have same issue but I have not found solution. Anyone is familiar with this issue and thinks updating to Android 5.1.1 would fix it?

Comment: Do you have a Bluetooth headset connected or Bluetooth turned on, though I think the icon would show up in that case?

Comment: No. I do not have  this.

Comment: How do you fix it?
I have same issue.

Comment: Post number 36 [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2393510&page=4) - would this help?

Comment: Do you have any downloaded apps which haven't been updated in about a year or more? One of them may be the cause. You could try uninstalling old, no-longer-updated apps to see if it fixes the problem. Or, you could start over with a [tag:factory-reset], which can take care of any downloaded app issues. If all else fails, I guess a manual flash of 5.1.1 (even an OTA update *might* work) will probably help.

Comment: Also, edit in a screenshot of your battery info screen from Settings. It might be the case that the app causing high CPU usage is *not* the app causing the battery drain.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury In the forum thread link that "blueren" posted there is one post that states apps is not an issue and that factory reset did not help. It's a spread problem.

Comment: By using top command I observe that when Quick System Info is launched, system_server starts consuming CPU via Binder threads. So probably your BuetoothPhoneService is not the cause.

Comment: @Denisigo After doing Factory Reset it occurs again. So maybe it's tied to Quick System Info due to how it monitors.

Comment: I have this problem on 2x totally unrelated devices (Note II, Transformer TF300T), though they are both rooted on custom ROMs on Android 5 and have Quick System info Pro in them.